# Reusing the same URL pattern in Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I'm building a simple web store. There are `Category` objects and `Product` objects.

I want the URLs for both to be at the top level, ie a `Category` named "Jacket" would be at http://example.com/jacket and a `Product` named "Foo" would be at http://example.com/foo.

I'm not sure how to handle this in my URLs since both match the same regular expression. I can just have a single `DetailView` which overwrites `get_object()`, first checking for a product with the slug and then checking for a category with the slug and returning whichever it finds first. (In the event of both a product and cateogry having the same slug, I'd want to serve the product.)

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The only better way to handle this is to follow best practice and namespace your objects in the url, i.e. http://example.com/products/foo and http://example.com/categories/jacket.

If you absolutely need everything to be at the root level domain (which is an uncommon need, makes adding any new routes at the root level more difficult, and gives way to ID collision as you mention in your question) I would suggest still setting up your URLs as I did above, and write a 3rd view that catches `r'^(?P<vanity>.+)/'` at the root level and possibly does a 302 to the correct URL. Something like this:

```
class CatchAllView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        vanity = kwargs.get('vanity')

        if Products.objects.filter(pk=vanity):
            return redirect('product', vanity=vanity)
        elif Categories.objects.filter(pk=vanity):
            return redirect('category', vanity=vanity)
        else:
            raise Http404("No such category or product.")
```

At least that way you'll actually have a URL to get to every product and category in the event there's a collision.